# nant build script task

Tags: nant

Compilation failed:
            c:\Users\miralp\AppData\Local\Temp_qjans4v.0.cs(36,6) : error CS0012: The type 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Xml, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
I am getting this error, the build file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Ttl.Deploy.Refunds.Functions.build" basedir="." xmlns="http://nant.sf.net/release/0.85/nant.xsd">

    <script language="C#" prefix="ttl" >
        <code>
            <references>
                    <include name="System.Xml.dll" />
                    <include name="System.dll" />       
                    <include name="System.IO.dll" />        
                    <include name="NAnt.Core.dll" />

                </references>
                <imports>
                    <import namespace="System.Xml" />
                    <import namespace="System" />
                    <import namespace="System.IO" />
                    <import namespace="NAnt.Core" />

                </imports>
            <![CDATA[
                [Function("expand_nant_properties_into_template")]
                public string Expand_nant_properties_into_template(string templateFilepath, string propertiesFilepath, string applicationVersion)
                {
                    const int INDENT_LEVEL = 0;
                    const string APPLICATION_VERSION = "applicationVersion";

                    //Get the contents of the template to be expanded
                    string template = new FileInfo(templateFilepath)
                                                .OpenText()
                                                .ReadToEnd();

                    //Create a new NAnt project with only the properties in the properties file
                    Project project = new Project(propertiesFilepath, Level.None, INDENT_LEVEL);
                    project.Properties.Add(APPLICATION_VERSION, applicationVersion);

                    //Load the properties into memory
                    project.Run();

                    return project.Properties.ExpandProperties(template, Location.UnknownLocation);
                }
            ]]>
        </code>
    </script>


</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `nant.settings.currentframework` property like this:

```
<property name="nant.settings.currentframework" value="net-3.5" />
```